# Validation that excludes itself on update action if fields have not changed

Tags: validation, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table called rents that hold a start and end date. I have then created a validation so that no new rents cant overlap existing rents start and end dates.

The thing is, when i click on a rent to update it and if i don't change any fields and click update. It trys to validate on itself and say that its overlapping an existing record. ( The existing record its referring to is it itself.)

The thing im trying to do is, how can i have my validation exclude itself. This is how my validation looks like.

```
def should_not_overlap_rental_periods
  errors.add(:start_date, "can't overlap other rental periods") if self.rents.where("end_date <= ? and start_date >= ?", self.end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), self.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")).count > 0 unless self.rents.blank? 
end
```

Comment: I've reformatted your code so that it appears in a code block. You might want to reformat it so that the contents of the method are not on a single line too wide to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check up on ActiveModel's Dirty Checking module. You can check on attributes if they have changed and branch your logic accordingly.

http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.1/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html